# Прогнозирование данных с помощью регрессии

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, визуализация, регрессия

Можно ли построить такую красную линию и продолжить её предсказание до определённой даты?

Данные были [взяты зздесь (owid-covid-data.csv)](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data).

Перерыл весь интернет, но нашёл такую [статью на хабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/496266/), где прогнозирование производится только при малой части данных с одной вершиной, а у меня как видно их две, но применяя его метод такая линия очень плохо ложится на мои данные:

```
corona =pd.read_csv("owid-covid-data.csv", parse_dates=['date'], sep=",")
corona['datecopy']=corona['date']
corona.set_index('datecopy', inplace=True)
corona.index = pd.to_datetime(corona.index)

chi = corona[corona['location']=='Russia']
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Confirmed Cases in Russia')
plt.xlabel('Dates')
plt.ylabel('Confirmed Cases')
plt.plot(chi['new_cases'].index, chi['new_cases'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Построить сглаженную кривую по *фактическим* данным очень просто:

```
ax = chi['new_cases'].plot(grid=True, figsize=(12, 6))

chi['new_cases'].rolling(15, center=True).mean().plot(grid=True, ax=ax, linewidth=2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для того, чтобы попытаться спрогнозировать число новых заразившихся COVID-19, нужно учитывать очень много факторов. Вот лишь некоторые из них:

1. сезонность распространения инфекционных заболеваний
2. реальные меры, предпринятые для того, чтобы остановить распространение заболевания - карантины, комендантский час, правила соблюдения личной защиты и гигиены и т.д.
3. средняя плотность населения и возможности свободно перемещаться
4. средняя дисциплинированность населения, культура и привычки. Например в азиатских странах с огромной плотностью населения уже давно существует привычка ношения масок в общественных местах - сравните сами скорость распространения COVID-19, например, в РФ и в Японии при схожем числе населения и совершенно несравнимой плотности населения.
5. и т.д. и т.п.

PS если рассматривать эту задачу как простую "time series", то можно попробовать построить регрессионные модели, используя [библиотеки схожие](https://python.libhunt.com/prophet-alternatives) с [FaceBook Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html), но не ожидайте при этом правдоподобных прогнозов.

Comment: Чуть дополню ответ. В данном процессе действительно небольшой период стабильности модели. Например, можно взять только последние месяцы(январь-апрель) и попробовать построить скорее всего нелинейную регрессию на несколько недель вперед.Такая модель будет полезна даже не для предсказания как такового, а для выявления точек изменения (change point detection), т.е. момента, когда в объекте происходит некоторое внутреннее изменение, которое мы можем зафиксировать по возросшей ошибке предсказания модели. В прикладном смысле это сигнал для специалистов "обрати внимание!" Очень важная задача, кстати.